# junit5 console launcher --scan-classpath argument does not restrict the test discovery classpath

Tags: junit5

I am using junit5 console launcher command line interface.
I have a couple of test jar files on the `-cp` argument (they have runtime dependancies between them, so cannot remove them) when calling `junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.2.jar`:

`tests1.jar` with contents:

```
com.mypackage.Test1
```

`tests2.jar` with contents:

```
com.mypackage.Test2
```

So my (overly simplified) arguments look like this:

`java -cp "C:/tests3.jar;C:/tests2.jar;C:/tests1.jar" --scan-classpath="C:/tests1.jar" --select-class="com.mypackage.Test1" org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher` -> this run should execute the test

`java -cp "C:/tests3.jar;C:/tests2.jar;C:/tests1.jar" --scan-classpath="C:/tests2.jar" --select-class="com.mypackage.Test1" org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher` -> this run should NOT execute the test

In the end both calls execute the test (probably because both jars are on the classpath) and I want only the first call to do it.

What am I doing wrong?

I used `--scan-classpath` argument to filter out the jar files which should be scanned for test discovery. I was hoping that tests only in this jar will be "seen" by the console launcher

I found those two issues: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/474 and https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/534 which mention the greedy `--include-classname` which I also use, but removing it has no effect. If the second jar is present on the classpath, the test always gets picked up :/